# Why do I get an old data set in one case after a GET request, and an up-to-date data set in the other

Tags: python, django

I make a POST request, enter the data into the table, but after that I do a Get and get the old data in this case

```
def get_queryset(self):
    transaction.commit()

    if self.action not in ['retrieve', 'list', 'create', 'selector']:
        res = self.queryset.filter(is_editable=True)
    else:
        res = self.queryset

    return res
```

Up-to-date data)

```
def get_queryset(self):
    transaction.commit()

    if self.action not in ['retrieve', 'list', 'create', 'selector']:
        res = self.queryset.filter(is_editable=True)
    else:
        res = Presence.objects.all()

    return res
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QuerySets cache the value. That means that if you directly return `self.queryset`, it will run the query *once*, and store the values in memory.

If you add `.all()`, you make a *copy* of the `QuerySet` *without* the cache, and you thus force making a new query.

This is why a `ListView` by default has an implementation where it will return the `queryset.all()`. Indeed, if we look at the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.0/django/views/generic/list.py#L28-L31), we see:

> ```
>     def get_queryset(self):
>         """
>         Return the list of items for this view.
>         The return value must be an iterable and may be an instance of
>         `QuerySet` in which case `QuerySet` specific behavior will be enabled.
>         """
>         if self.queryset is not None:
>             queryset = self.queryset
>             if isinstance(queryset, QuerySet):
>                 queryset = queryset.all()
>         elif self.model is not None:
>             queryset = self.model._default_manager.all()
>         else:
>             raise ImproperlyConfigured(
>                 "%(cls)s is missing a QuerySet. Define "
>                 "%(cls)s.model, %(cls)s.queryset, or override "
>                 "%(cls)s.get_queryset()." % {
>                     'cls': self.__class__.__name__
>                 }
>             )
>         ordering = self.get_ordering()
>         if ordering:
>             if isinstance(ordering, str):
>                 ordering = (ordering,)
>             queryset = queryset.order_by(*ordering)
>
>         return queryset
> ```